# Reference request for showing open(resp. closed) string field theory has A-infinity(resp. L-infinity) algebra structure

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, a-infinity-algebras

I've now begun to study about the relationship between open(resp. closed) string field theory and A-infinity(resp. L-infinity) algebra structure.

For the A-infinity case, I'd already heard that the bubbling pheonomenon gives such algebraic structure to the de Rham complex of Lagrangian submanifold under specific assumption (in the context of Floer type theory), and lecturer says that there is an analogy for L-infinity algebra.

I thought it is very intriguing fact, and so I tried to find books or references to learn such things in detail.

I've found H. Kajiua, J. Stasheff's  and it cites many references for this topic in the first line. But, I don't know what are good papers on which I drill down.

I would like to ask the recommended references which contains explanation about this.
I'm familiar with symplectic geometry, and Floer theoretic concepts and so, I prefer this approach, but other approaches are also okay.

Comment: How about Algebraic Structure of String Field Theory?

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/303053054X/ref=ox_sc_saved_title_5?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1

Comment: I'll have a check in detail. I skimmed the TOC of the book and it seems.. what I look forward.